# How to find/install required package version when not available

Tags: ubuntu, libxml2, apt

Installing a demo server of [popHealth project](https://github.com/pophealth/popHealth/wiki/Installation-v2.1). I get the following error when running the following installation command:

```
bundle exec rake bundle:import[/home/pophealth/bundle-2.6.0.zip,false,false,'*',true,true] RAILS_ENV=development
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8
/home/<removed>/popHealth/lib/tasks/sharding.rake:4: warning: class variable access from toplevel
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/pophealth/bundle-2.6.0.zip
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/health-data-standards-3.5.3/lib/health-data-standards/tasks/bundle.rake:41:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/health-data-standards-3.5.3/lib/health-data-standards/tasks/bundle.rake:41:in `open'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/health-data-standards-3.5.3/lib/health-data-standards/tasks/bundle.rake:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => bundle:import
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

So it appears I need a later version of LibXML, right? Research, research....
Issue this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libxml2 libxml2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libxml2 is already the newest version.
libxml2-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So I am at a loss. Obviously there is a later version of libxml2, but I cannot get it upgraded. I am guessing that I need to configure my system to search for it somewhere else, but I am at a loss of how to do that. Assuming that is correct, the big questions I have are:

1) How do I find a repo that includes the version of libxml2 that I need to install.

2) Once I find that repo, how do I configure apt-get to use that repo instead.

Comment: what is the version of libxml2 that you have installed?

Comment: WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8

Comment: Why the down vote - is this not a legitimate question?